# Insert data into postgreSQL using nodejs typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql

My code looks like this

```js
signup.post('/signup', urlendcodedParser, async(req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;
    const age = req.body.age;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const fullname = req.body.fullname;
    console.log(req.body)
    
    await pool.query("INSERT INTO (username, userpassword, email, fullname, age) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING *", [username, password ,email, fullname, age]).catch(err => console.log(err))
    await res.json("Akaunt napravljen")
})
```

But when I try to submit a POST request I get this error:

error: syntax error at or near "("
at Parser.parseErrorMessage (C:\Users\prcap\Desktop\liveno-t\server\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\parser.ts:369:69)
at Parser.handlePacket (C:\Users\prcap\Desktop\liveno-t\server\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\parser.ts:188:21)
at Parser.parse (C:\Users\prcap\Desktop\liveno-t\server\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\parser.ts:103:30)
at Socket. (C:\Users\prcap\Desktop\liveno-t\server\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\index.ts:7:48)
at Socket.emit (events.js:375:28)
at Socket.emit (domain.js:470:12)
at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:290:12)
at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:265:9)
at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:204:10)
at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) {
length: 90,
severity: 'ERROR',
code: '42601',
detail: undefined,
hint: undefined,
position: '13',
internalPosition: undefined,
internalQuery: undefined,
where: undefined,
schema: undefined,
table: undefined,
column: undefined,
dataType: undefined,
constraint: undefined,
file: 'scan.l',
line: '1180',
routine: 'scanner_yyerror'
}

How can I fix this?

Comment: Your query is missing the name of the table that you want to insert into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the table name.

```
INSERT INTO table_name (username, userpassword, email)...
```